# About the inputs of the Wasserstein Distance W1

Tags: python, scipy, data-science, probability-distribution

**NOTE: I wrote the same question on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4765025/about-the-inputs-of-the-wasserstein-distance-w-1, and since I did not get any comment or answer, I post it here, since it can overlap with topics on stack overflow**

In math, you calculate the Wasserstein Distance W1 among two probability measures P and Q, by using the CDFs (or the inverse CDFs) of those two probability measures P and Q, i.e. F and G (or F<sup>-1</sup> and G<sup>-1</sup>).

In Python (please see [scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance.html)), you use the "*Values observed in the (empirical) distributions*" as inputs to calculate the Wasserstein Distance W1. Therefore:

1. What are the "*Values observed in the (empirical) distributions*" mentioned in Python guidelines as inputs for calculating W1? I mean, do they refer to the empirical estimations of Probability Density Functions, i.e. histograms, or to the empirical Cumulative Distribution Functions (eCDFs)?
2. How are the inputs used in Python related to the two probability measures P and Q?

Comment: sorry I cannot find your question in Mathematics. The link you provided doesn't seem to go to your question

Comment: Sorry, you are right, the link was broken

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4765025/about-the-inputs-of-the-wasserstein-distance-w-1

Comment: Please do not post entire questions as images. This ruins accessibility.

Comment: @jared, it looks like that the Latex code does not work here... how to do ?

Comment: @jared I changed the question... just text now, with a reference to the full version on math stackexchange... better now?

Comment: @limone LaTeX formatting doesn't exist on Stack Overflow since this is a coding site, not a mathematics/physics site.

Comment: Ah ok, I did not know, thanks!

Comment: @limone you could still do subscripts/superscripts with **sub** and **sup** tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about SciPy and how they compute Wasserstein Distance, I used Python OT (optimal transport) package to compute Wasserstein Distance from samples.

Internally, I believe, OT computes empirical CDF from samples and then distance as integral.

Sample code, Python 3.10 Windows x64

```
import ot
import numpy as np

#%%

tab1 = np.random.normal(2, 1, 1000)
tab2 = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)

q = ot.wasserstein_1d(tab1,tab2)
print(q)
```

prints value around 2

Link to the package page https://pythonot.github.io/

Comment: Many thanks @Severin Pappadeux! From the python guidelines, it looks like that  ```numpy.random.normal``` are probability density functions PDFs (of gaussian distribution). This means that, quite likely, ```ot.wasserstein_1d``` takes two PDFs and it transform them "internally" into CDFs.... This is what I understand... :-)

Comment: @limone No, numpy.random.normal is  a sampling routine. tab1 and tab2 will be 1000 gaussian samples from N(2,1) and N(0,1). And I believe numpy.random.normal builds CDFs directly from samples

Comment: I mean ot.wasserstein_1d() builds CDFs directly from samples

Comment: Yes yes, I understood... so basically this goes directly from samples to CDFs, without building up the PDFs... clear... :-)